# select highest value in Raster stack and show layer name as legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I have got a raster stack of 4 raster and created a single raster with each cell showing the highest value across the 4 layers as follows:

```
library(raster)
stack_raster <- list()
var_name <- c("tmax","tmin","drought","flood")
for(i in seq_along(var_name)){
    var_ref <- var_name[i]
    r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
    names(r) <- var_ref
    set.seed(i)
    values(r) <- sample(100)
    stack_raster[[i]] <- r
  }

s <- raster::stack(stack_raster)
max_raster <- whiches.max(s)
plot(max_raster)
```

[image]

However, in the legend, instead of showing the values, I want to show the
the name of actual raster that contributed to that value. How can I create such map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `which.max(s)` instead of `whiches.max(s)`. Then, to plot, the easiest thing is probably to `melt` the raster into a data frame and assign the labels to the `value` column and use `ggplot` to draw the result with `geom_tile` or `geom_raster`

```r
max_raster <- which.max(s)
df <- reshape2::melt(as.matrix(max_raster))
df$value <- factor(var_name[df$value], var_name)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan. I need to read the documentation on how `which.max` deals with ties in case for a grid, two layers have the same value.

Comment: @89_Simple `which.max` will consider the vector of elements at each x, y location in the stack, and in the case of ties will choose the one nearest the bottom of the stack (i.e. the one with the lowest index)