# Finding maximum value in a big raster stack take too much time

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a raster stack of 7 rasters. Each raster has the following properties

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 21600, 43200, 933120000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : tmax.tif 
names      : tmax 
values     : 1, 100  (min, max)
```

I want to create a single raster that has for each grid, the maximum value across the 7 rasters. I thought I would do this following a solution proposed here:

[select highest value in Raster stack and show layer name as legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71922729/select-highest-value-in-raster-stack-and-show-layer-name-as-legend/71922875?noredirect=1#comment127091666_71922875)

```
max_raster <- which.max(my_raster_stack)
df <- reshape2::melt(as.matrix(max_raster))
df$value <- factor(var_name[df$value], var_name)
```

However, due to sheer size of the raster stack, it's taking my hours to do this (still waiting for it to finish). Does anyone know any quicker way to do this?

Comment: `raster::maxValue(my_raster_stack)` ?

Comment: Thanks and also apologies. My question was not clear on the final output. I want to create a single raster based on the 7 rasters that I have and each grid should contain the maximum value across the 7 rasters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max` to get the maximum value of each cell. Here with `terra` (the replacement of raster, but it works the same with raster)

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f, f) * 1:6
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#names       : lyr1, lyr2, lyr3, lyr4, lyr5, lyr6 
#min values  :    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0 
#max values  :  255,  510,  765, 1020, 1275, 1530
```

Solution

```
x <- max(r)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        :  max 
#min value   :    0 
#max value   : 1530
```

To find out, for each grid cell, which layer has the maximum value (or the first one if there are ties), you can do

```
w <- which.max(r)
w
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        : which.max 
#min value   :         1 
#max value   :         6
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. Quick question: How do I figure out which layer the maximum value is coming from for each grid?

Comment: You can use `which.max` see my expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have a separate question regarding `terra` package. How to read '.gri' file. I can read it using `raster::raster` but if I do `terra::rast`, I get error `not recognized as a supported file format`. Should I post this as a separate question in SO?

Comment: well, yes, normally that would be a separate question. But the answer is use `.grd` instead.